# (c++) overriding operator<< prints wrong object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm now doing operator overriding for scalar and vector and struggling with operator<<

Here is my code first

main: (I cannot change the main... it will be given like this and I only code cpVector, cpScalar)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cpScalar.hpp"
#include "cpVector.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

cpScalar arr[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    arr[i] = cpScalar(i+1);
}
cpVector v1(arr, 4);          // {1, 2, 3, 4}
cpScalar arr2[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    arr2[i] = cpScalar(i+3);
}
cpVector v2(arr2, 4);         // {3, 4, 5, 6}

cpVector result4 = v2 / v1;   //  {0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6}

cout << result4.getVal(0) << " " ... " "  << result4.getVal(3) << endl;
cout << result4 << endl;
// prints   0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6   and     [, , , ]
}
```

When I check each value of result 4, I can find operator/ worked.
However, when I try to print the whole vector, it prints an empty value.
Here is cpVector class.

cpVector:

```
#ifndef CPVECTOR_H
#define CPVECTOR_H
#include "cpScalar.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;
class cpVector
{
    private:
        cpScalar *data;
        unsigned int size;

    public:
        cpVector() {
            cpScalar s[0];
            data = s;
            size = 0;
        }

        cpVector(cpScalar sarr[], unsigned int s){
            this->size = s;
            data = sarr;
        }

        cpVector operator/(cpVector s){
            assert(size == s.getSize());

            unsigned int x = s.getSize();
            cpScalar denom = s.getAbs();
            cpScalar ans[x];
            for (int i=0; i < x;i++){
                ans[i] = data[i] / denom;
                std::cout << i << "th element: " << ans[i] << std::endl;
            }
            return cpVector(ans, x);
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const cpVector &r);

        cpScalar getVal(int i)const{return data[i];}

        int getSize() const{return size;}

        cpScalar getAbs() const{
            cpScalar sum(0);
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                cpScalar x = data[i];
                if(x.getDouble() < 0 && x.getInt() < 0){
                    x = x * cpScalar(-1);
                }
                sum = sum + x;
            }
            return sum;
        }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const cpVector &r) {
            s.put('[');
            if(r.getSize() > 0){
                s << r.getVal(0);
                for (int i = 1; i < r.getSize(); i++) {
                    s << ", " << r.getVal(i);
                }
            }
            return s << ']';
        };

#endif // CPVECTOR_H
```

cpScalar:

```
#ifndef CPSCALAR_H
#define CPSCALAR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

const int invalid = 99999999;

class cpScalar
{
     private:
        int intData;
        double doubData;
        char dType;

    public:
        cpScalar() {
            intData = invalid;
            doubData = invalid;
            dType = ' ';
        }
        cpScalar(int d) {
            intData = d;
            doubData = invalid;
            dType = 'i';
        }
        cpScalar(double d) {
            intData = invalid;
            doubData = d;
            dType = 'd';
        }

        cpScalar operator+ (cpScalar &s){
            if (getType() == 'i' && s.getType() == 'i'){
                return cpScalar(getInt() + s.getInt());
            }else if (getType() == 'd' && s.getType() == 'i'){
                return cpScalar(getDouble() + s.getInt());
            }else if (getType() == 'i' && s.getType() == 'd'){
                return cpScalar(getInt() + s.getDouble());
            } else if (getType() == 'd' && s.getType() == 'd'){
                return cpScalar(getDouble() + s.getDouble());
            }
            return cpScalar(invalid);
        }

        cpScalar operator/ (cpScalar s){
            assert(s.getDouble() != 0 && s.getInt() != 0);

            if (getType() == 'i' && s.getType() == 'i'){
                if(getInt() % s.getInt() == 0) return cpScalar(getInt() / s.getInt());
                else return cpScalar(1.0 * getInt() / s.getInt());
            }else if (getType() == 'd' && s.getType() == 'i'){
                return cpScalar(getDouble() / s.getInt());
            }else if (getType() == 'i' && s.getType() == 'd'){
                return cpScalar(getInt() / s.getDouble());
            } else if (getType() == 'd' && s.getType() == 'd'){
                return cpScalar(getDouble() / s.getDouble());
            }
            return cpScalar(invalid);
        }

        cpScalar operator* (cpScalar s){
            if (getType() == 'i' && s.getType() == 'i'){
                return cpScalar(getInt() * s.getInt());
            }else if (getType() == 'd' && s.getType() == 'i'){
                return cpScalar(getDouble() * s.getInt());
            }else if (getType() == 'i' && s.getType() == 'd'){
                return cpScalar(getInt() * s.getDouble());
            } else if (getType() == 'd' && s.getType() == 'd'){
                return cpScalar(getDouble() * s.getDouble());
            }
            return cpScalar(invalid);
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &sout, const cpScalar &d);

        int getInt() const{return intData;}

        double getDouble() const{return doubData;}

        char getType() const{return dType;}

};
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &sout, const cpScalar &d) {
            if(d.getType() == 'i') sout << d.getInt();
            else if (d.getType() == 'd') sout << d.getDouble();
            return sout;
        };
#endif // CPSCALAR_H
```

Thanks for the reading

Comment: We need a [mcve] to be able to help.

Comment: Is this where we all have to *guess* what a `cpVector` is and how it relates to `myVector` (if at all) ? Post a [mcve]. If we can compile *what you posted* and get the same error you are getting, you did it right. Otherwise, it's soothsaying, and that isn't what this site is about.

Comment: `result4` is a `cpVector` but your `operator<<` expects a `myVector`.

Comment: Oh I've wrote it wrong on here they are all myVectors in code. Edited the stackoverflow

Comment: Still not a [mcve], you'll probably find the bug is in the code you haven't considered and haven't posted

Comment: @AlanBirtles Uploaded most of the part related (other overriding operators are turned into comments, and didn't upload basic getters etc.). Now little concerned about being too long :/ Thank you for advisory about writing a question on here.

Comment: Still not a [mcve] but you are taking pointers to temporaries in your `cpVector` constructors which will produce undefined behaviour

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you for the comment. I have question for the code and Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example 1. Is there any other way to have array as a class member, not using pointer and not in a constant length?  2. Is the question bad because it is too long? or should I also upload such as getSize() to make it run on the IDE right away? Thank you

Comment: You just described a `std::vector`. Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to create and resize vectors, and read it.

Comment: It makes it much easier for people to see the issue in your code if they can just copy and paste it and run it themselves. Assuming you aren't allowed to use `std::vector` then you'll have to use `new` and `delete` to create arrays on the heap rather than the stack. Ideally you'd use `std::unique`/`std::shared_ptr` but you probably aren't allowed to use those either.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you! I've edited complete code related to main. Maybe I was too concentrating on the word 'Minimal'. I guess I should try `new` and `delete`

Comment: I've taken your code and removed the pointers to temporaries and it fixes the issue.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Still struggling with temporary (please understand as I learned c++ only two weeks), but I'm kinda figuring out. Thank you for the help and kindness. Have a charming day :)

Comment: `cpScalar s[0];` seriously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store a pointer to a temporary variable allocated on the stack. When the temporary ceases to exist at the end of its scope the pointer is no longer valid.

For example with the following code (note, I've omitted initialisation of the array values in these examples for brevity):

```
struct Foo
{
  int* data;
  Foo( int* d )
  : data( d )
  {
  }
};

Foo makeFoo( size_t size )
{
  int bar[ size ]; // note this in invalid c++, only allowed by a gcc extension
  return Foo( bar );
}

int main()
{
  Foo f = makeFoo( 4 );
  std::cout << f.data[ 0 ]; // undefined behaviour, f.data points to and array that no longer exists
}
```

The array `bar` doesn't exist after the end of `makeFoo` and the returned `Foo`'s `data` pointer points to memory which has been deallocated. Note, if you run the above code it will likely print the correct output as although the array no longer exists it's values won't have been overwritten as no other function will have used the stack before we print the output.

The most C++ solution to this problem is to use `std::vector`:

```
struct Foo
{
  std::vector< int > data;
  Foo( const std::vector< int >& data )
  : data( d ) // make a copy of the temporary vector, no more undefined behaviour
  {
  }
};

Foo makeFoo( size_t size )
{
  std::vector< int > bar( size );
  return Foo( bar );
}
```

If your assignment doesn't let you use `std::vector` (I hate assignments that try to teach you C++ by not allowing you to use key features of the language and standard library) then you will need to use pointers:

```
struct Foo
{
  int* data;
  Foo( int* d )
  : data( d )
  {
  }
};

Foo makeFoo( size_t size )
{
  int* bar = new int[ size ];
  return Foo( bar );
}
```

You will need to make sure you implement a destructor which calls `delete[]` on the array or you will have a memory leak and take note of the [rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and implement or delete the copy constructor and assignment operator.

To avoid this issue we should make use of `std::unique_ptr` which deletes the array for us and avoids the rule of 3/5 issue:

```
struct Foo
{
    std::unique_ptr< int[] > data;
    Foo(std::unique_ptr< int[] >&& d)
        : data( std::move( d ) )
    {
    }
};

Foo makeFoo(size_t size)
{
    std::unique_ptr< int[] > bar( new int[ size ] ); 
    return Foo( std::move( bar ) );
}
```

Note as it is not possible to copy a `std::unique_ptr` we have to use `std::move` to move the values rather than copying them. You would also need to use `std::move:` to move Foo objects around rather than copying them. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor for information on how moving objects work in C++ (may be a bit advanced for a beginner but is a key feature of modern C++). If you can't get your head around moving objects you could use `std::shared_ptr` instead (just replace `std::unique_ptr` with `std::shared_ptr` in the above example and remove the `std::move`s) which is copyable, but note that if you copy a `Foo` object both copies will be pointing to the *same* data.